# Angular4 mask characters in Input without changing its value

Tags: angular

How can I mask all characters (i.e. show *) in input except last four in Angular 4 without changing the actual value?

For example: number should look like ***1234 inside input textbox and the value should be 7671234.

Answer (score 2):

Use a directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[stringHide]'
})
export class StringDirective implements OnInit {
  private value: any;  //the variable where we save the "true value"
  private element: HTMLInputElement
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private form: ControlContainer) {
    this.element = el.nativeElement;
  }
  ngOnInit() { //It's necesary use OnInit, otherwise the first time not formtted
    this.value = this.element.value;
    this.formatValue();
  }
  @HostListener('input') onChange() {  //when a change happens save the value in a variable
    this.value = this.element.value;   
  }
  @HostListener('blur') onBlur() { //when lost the focus call format function
    this.formatValue();
  }
  @HostListener('focus') onFocus() { //when get the focus recover the true value
    this.element.value = this.value;
  }
  formatValue() { //here, change the apperance of the input
                  //I choose that if the value.length>14 only show 10 "*"
    let len=this.element.value.length;
    this.element.value = (len <= 4) ? this.element.value:
                         (len>14)? "**********"+this.element.value.substr(len - 4):
                               "**************".substring(0,len-4)+this.element.value.substr(len - 4);
  }
}
```

Comment: Will this work if you move the cursor in the input box?

Comment: The directive works fine in a Reactive Form. there is a problem when this directive it's used with template driven forms. If I'll resolve I'll change the code

Comment: What If I need an input of type="number" (for reactive forms to perform min max validations but want to show the number 1234.56 as 1.234,56 (my locale inverts "." and "," separators) I tried to use decimalPipe.transform, but the type of the input clears the box.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the directive in a TemplateDriveForm you must add AfterViewChecked event because in ngOnInit we cannot get the "real value"

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[stringHide]'
})
export class StringDirective implements OnInit,AfterViewChecked { //<--AddAfterViewChecked
private value: any; 
private initialized:boolean; //<--add a new variable
....
//Add ngAfterViewCheckecd 
ngAfterViewChecked()
{
   if (this.element.value && !this.initialized)
   {
      this.initialized=true;
      this.value = this.element.value;
      this.formatValue();
    }
 }
 .....
```