# Format number without clicking on the field Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I found a directive that uses a pipe to format a number in the input. For example 1000 - 1,000. But for this you need to click on the field. I can not bind the transformation function to load the page. I tried to do so:

```
@HostListener('load', ['$event']) onPageLoad(event: Event) 
   onBlur(value) {
        this.el.value = this.currencyPipe.transform(value);
    }
```

Here is the code of the directive, which I did not correctly do?

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { MyCurrencyPipe } from "./my-currency.pipe";

@Directive({ selector: "[myCurrencyFormatter]" })
export class MyCurrencyFormatterDirective implements OnInit {

    private el: any;

    constructor(
        private elementRef: ElementRef,
        private currencyPipe: MyCurrencyPipe
    ) {
        this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.el.value = this.currencyPipe.transform(this.el.value);
    }

    @HostListener("focus", ["$event.target.value"])
    onFocus(value) {
        this.el.value = this.currencyPipe.parse(value); // opossite of transform
    }

    @HostListener("blur", ["$event.target.value"])
    onBlur(value) {
        this.el.value = this.currencyPipe.transform(value);
    }

    @HostListener('load', ["$event.target.value"])
    onload(value) {
        this.el.value = this.currencyPipe.transform(value);
    }

}
```

Comment: show us the HTML file where you are trying to use this pipe

Comment: In a Template drive form (using ngModel) you must use AfterViewChecked one time, see the example in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47611181/angular4-mask-characters-in-input-without-changing-its-value/47613647#47613647